# Phalcon Micro "handle()" method decodes URI

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

My Phalcon Micro application receives URI parts with encoded slashes (%2F).

For example, before calling `$app->handle()`:

```
echo $app->request->getURI(); // -> /resources/res%2F01/all
```

But it looks like the `$app->handle()` method is decoding my URI, converting my %2F to a slash. Thus, the following routing rule...

```
$app->get('/resources/{code:[^\/]+}/all', function() { /* ... */ });
```

... will not work properly since %2F is now a slash. Controller-side, the %2F is no longer present.

```
echo $code // -> res/01
```

Is there a way to tell Phalcon to not decode URIs?

---

**EDIT**

In the end, Phalcon is not decoding the URI, but is based on the `$_GET['_url']` parameter for its routing, and the %2F code is already missing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is not accepted by route regexp. You disallow slashes in route definition - `[^\/]+`.

If you want to route match this url, route definition must looks like:

```
$app->get('/resources/{code:.+}/all', function() { /* ... */ });
```

> Is there a way to tell Phalcon to not decode URIs?

I think no.

Comment: Nice. I thought the `.+` regex would also take the `/all` part, looks like it isn't. As for Phalcon, after looking at the sources, it looks like it is not decoding the URI but is based on $_GET['_url'] and the %2F is already missing there.